# downloading a file from sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a few basic question about downloading file from share point online.

My company has a sharepoint site called

https://abc.sharepoint.com --> ( all sharepoint online url's end with sharepoint.com, hope this is clear)

my doubt is when i try to automate the download from this site using the python packages like

Office365-REST-Python-Client

do i need to have a office 365 account or i can use my company's official email account or to be more clear

Does this code work for organisation accounts like myname@domain.mycompany.com or

we need to have a proper office365 account like myname@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com ?

Any thought on this would be helpful

Comment: Ask your company's IT department about how they've configured access to their Sharepoint site.

Comment: Ok but what i wanted to know is how this(Office365-REST-Python-Client) python package operates whether it uses  office 365 login like myname@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/master/examples/settings.py

if you check this link they have used an office 365 id for testing the codes.

'username': 'mattim@mediadev23.onmicrosoft.com',

which means this would work only if you have an valid Office 365 Id and not just an login like

abc@mycompany.com

so in order to use the above package we need to get an office 365 account from the organization you work.